# get data from querystring with python

Tags: python, query-string

I have a querystring like `a=2&b=3` created by `serialize()` jQuery.
How to get `a` and `b` with a Python function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

python2: [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)

python3: [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)

Comment: it seems urlparse.parse_qs() get query string from url. i need to get a and b separately like a=2 b=3

Comment: need to get a and b separately like a=2 b=3

Comment: What other idea could you possibly need? Did you try looking at the returned dictionary?

Comment: ... Stop picking random functions and use the one I gave you.

Comment: what is this error? when i run this code:  urlparse.parse_qs('a=1&b=2')   'function' object has no attribute 'parse_qs'

Comment: You goofed up and imported `urlparse` from `urlparse`.